# Is this a thread safe way to control access to a reusable resource? Is there a better way?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

```
public static class ThreadStatic<T> where T : new()
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static T instance;

    public static T Instance
    {
        get { return instance ?? (instance = new T()); }
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
var probability = ThreadStatic<Random>.Instance.NextDouble();
```

1. Can this be broken? (Like, am I missing a `volatile` somewhere?)
2. Is there an existing pattern for this?  Is there a better way to do this?
3. What would be an elegant way to allow for constructor parameters to be specified?
4. Would this be better suited to an IOC container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I'm not sure to be honest, the contained resource would be specific per thread and created upon first read so volatile may be unnecessary as I believe that's for multiple threads reading and writing to the same field.
2. It looks like you are trying to make a singleton version of the [ThreadLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) class, unless you have a good reason I would suggest that you just use that instead.
3. The ThreadLocal class allows for a factory method (as a `Func<T>`) to be supplied to create a more complex object.
4. It depends on the type of resource you want to use in this manner, if it is a service or resource then yes an IOC may be a better option as most containers allow an instance per thread. However if you just need per thread storage of a field, then `ThreadLocal` is a better option. It also allows the resource to be properly disposed if required too.

Comment: I was not aware of the `ThreadLocal<T>` class.

Comment: @JohnGietzen given the size of the .net framework these days I'm not surprised! It wasn't introduced until .NET 4 either so it's relatively new too.